# Getting error/null for a bidirectional graphQL query

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I am working my way through a tutorial for graphQL and it seems that it may be outdated possibly. The issue I am currently having is that in my schema.js file we are trying to create a bidirectional query between a Company Type and a User Type.

When checking the query string that should be produce it shows the correct data but when working in the GraphiQl side the query throws an error and/or shows that the user field is null and I am not sure why.

```
    const CompanyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Company',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLString },
        name: { type: GraphQLString} ,
        description: { type: GraphQLString },
        users: {
            type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
            resolve(parentValue, args) {
                return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/companies/${parentValue.id}/users`)
                    .then(res => res.data)
            }
        }
    })
});

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLString},
        firstName: { type: GraphQLString},
        age: { type: GraphQLInt},
        company: {
            type: CompanyType,
            resolve(parentValue, args) {
                return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/companies/${parentValue.companyId}`)
                    .then(res => res.data);
            }
        }
    })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLString } },
            resolve(parentValue, args) {
                return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/${args.id}`)
                    .then(res => res.data)
            }
        },
        company: {
            type: CompanyType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLString } },
            resolve(parentValue, args) {
                return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/companies/${args.id}`)
                    .then(res => res.data)
            }
        }

    }
});
```

That is the current schema.js file that I am working off of and the package.json file is as followed:

```
{
  "name": "users",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "json:server": "json-server --watch db.json",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Am I missing/overlooking something or is the solution that I guess that's being presented to me currently out of date?

Comment: Which query? what error?

Comment: ... tutorial - link? REST response shape/data examples?